# Run Python script from a Laravel application

Tags: python, laravel

I want to run my Python script in Laravel.
When I press the run button in the browser it runs my Python script and displays output on the page through a controller....

I tried so many ways but the script in not going to run...

Am also using

```php
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
```

But when I run the code it just blinks the terminal and nothing else...

Please guide me on how to run a Python script from Laravel.

Comment: When asking questions you should be more specific about what you tried and what is not working. This questions borders on [Help Vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire) territory by effectively asking for a full tutorial. Please be considerate of the time of others; that way you also support the community.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have installed `symfony/process` via composer

```sh
composer require symfony/process
```

And you have a form in your view that points to an action with a button

```html
<form action="/" method="post">
    @csrf
    <button type="submit">Run Python</button>
</form>
```

And a route in `routes/web.php` that points to the controller

```php
Route::post('/', 'PythonController@run');
```

And a Python script named `python.py` in the root of your Laravel application directory with the content

```py
print("Hello, World from Python!")
```

And a controller method that runs the process and returns the output

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class PythonController extends Controller
{
    public function run(Request $request)
    {
        $process = new Process(['python', base_path() . '/python.py']);
        $process->run();
        return $process->getOutput();
    }
}
```

You would have a view like so
[image: Laravel Blade View]

And when the button is clicked, you'd get the Python output like so
[image: Python Output]

Comment: @'Salim Djerbouh'  where you place the python.py file....in controller folder or view folder

Comment: I placed it in the main folder (alongside composer.json)

Comment: i placed my file in main folder but is not working yet...please help me brother

Comment: I need to see your code and a screenshot of your folder structure

Comment: can you access my pc through remotely like teamviewer or something else....brother

Comment: @SalimDjerbouh This is an awesome answer for a rather undeserving question.

Comment: @ZulfiqarKhan It is bad form to ask others to work on your code - unless you intend to pay them. And even if you genuinely only want help, it is rather suspect to ask people to log into your machine.

Comment: This help me run my python file, but i'm using `rembg` library, which is not working with `Laravel`, but works fine with terminal and python